# Why the title of the View does not change, but a new string is added next to it when I use the method setTitle()?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-9

The view page has an exposed filter by field category. When choosing a category, I need to change the title of the view (view uses Ajax) to the selected category in the filter. Since by default the title of the view is not displayed on the page, I added it to the view template:

```
{{view.title}}
```

And the default title was displayed on the view page: `product-list`.

I change the title like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_render().
 */
function entity_product_admin_views_post_render(ViewExecutable $view, array &$output, CachePluginBase $cache) {
  $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $category_id = $view->getExposedInput()['product_category'];

  if ($category_id !== NULL) {
    $category_node = $storage->load($category_id);
    $category_name = $category_node->get('field_name')->getString();
    $title = $category_name;
    $view->setTitle($title);
  }

}
```

But instead of changing the title from **product-list** to the **selected category** (e.g. Accessories), it adds a newly selected category each time:

**product-list Accessories**

After one more change the filter value to Sweatshirts:
**product-list Accessories Sweatshirts**

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`$view->setTitle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AsetTitle/9.3.x) in a post_render hook is not a good idea because it only affects the view on further rendering, because the tokens in the title gets replaced *before* rendering. In this context (post render), you should only override the `$output` render array, not the view object itself.

Also, the title is not displayed by default because the **template variable 'title' is empty by default** (except on live-preview in the admin UI) and not necessarily because `$view->getTitle()` is empty. You should already have a `{{ title }}` variable in your template and you probably just need to set it instead of adding `{{view.title}}`.

Now, you can set this variable by setting `$output['title']` in a post render hook, or by setting `$variables['title']` in a preprocess hook.

For example, here is how [Views UI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21views_ui.module/function/views_ui_preprocess_views_view/9.3.x) sets the title on live preview :

```php
function views_ui_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  // Render title for the admin preview.
  if (!empty($view->live_preview)) {
    $variables['title'] = [
      '#markup' => $view->getTitle()
    ];
  }

  // ...
}
```